# Dynamically appending one list into another

Tags: python, list

I have following very simple implementation in python

```
 m = []
 l = []
 l.append('A')
 l.append('B')
 l.append('C')
 m.append(l)
 l.clear()
 print(m) --> this gives empty list.
```

i tried

```
 m = []
 l = []
 n = []
 l.append('A')
 l.append('B')
 l.append('C')
 n = l
 m.append(n)
 l.clear()
 print(m) --> this gives empty list too
```

But when i do not clear l, print(m) give me desired list which is ['A','B','C']. Why python clears list m when i clear list l. they are 2 separate variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are passing a list to another list then it is taking its reference there
So when you cleared that list your original list's element is also cleared
Try this

```
m = []
l = []
l.append('A')
l.append('B')
l.append('C')
m.append(l.copy())  -> use list.copy()
l.clear()
print(m)
```

Comment: What i was doing was perfect example of 'little knowledge is dangerous'.

Answer (score 2):

Both variables are reference pointing to the same object. to make a new list you need to use `n = l[:]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `list.copy`:

```
m.append(l[:])
```

or

```
m.append(list(l))
```

The will append to `m` a "freshly" created list.

In some situations also a [*deep copy*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of the object could be the right solution:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
m.append(deepcopy(l))
...
```